# Fields search does not return field values

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to select only specific fields in my search over index with >100 fields using NEST client. 
The search returns 10K results as expected, but when looping over hits field values dictionary is null (I see it in debugger).
Below is the code:

```
var elastic = new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(defaultIndex: "customer"));

var result = elastic.Search<Customer>(s => s.Fields(new[] { "AccountNumber", "Folder" })
            .From(0).Size(10000).SortDescending(c => c.DateAdded)
            .Query(q => q.Term(c => c.Language, "english")));

    foreach (var res in result.Hits)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(res.Fields.FieldValues<Customer, int>(c => c.AccountNumber).First() +
            " " + res.Fields.FieldValues<Customer, int>(c => c.Folder).First());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Query Elapsed MS: {0}", result.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Doing same search without fields filter and iterating over documents works correctly.

Update: when searching without fields filter and iterating over hits fields property is also null.

Comment: May you share mapping?

Comment: [ElasticType(IdProperty = "AccountNumber")]
        public class Customer
        {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your search as follow:

```
elastic.Search<Customer>(s => s.Fields(new[] { "accountNumber", "folder" })
            .From(0).Size(10000).SortDescending(c => c.DateAdded)
            .Query(q => q.Term(c => c.Language, "english")));
```

Why it works? Because NEST by default camelCase propeties, so when you will check your mapping you will see something like:

```
{
    "indexname" : {
        "mappings" : {
            "document" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "accountNumber" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "folder" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "id" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see there is no field like AccountNumber or Folder.

To deal with it, you can:

1. Leave property names untouched by setting

   ```
   settings.SetDefaultPropertyNameInferrer(p=>p);
   ```
2. Change you search:

   ```
   var result = elastic.Search<Customer>(s => s.Fields(f => f.AccountNumber, f => f.Folder))
               .From(0).Size(10000).SortDescending(c => c.DateAdded)
               .Query(q => q.Term(c => c.Language, "english")));
   ```